# Select random combinations of list elements such that no list element is present in more than one selection (SQL)

Tags: javascript, sql, random, combinations

I'm running a bit out of ideas how to realize a small project.

*What I have:*
- a list of users including their ID and name

*What I want to achieve:*
- I want to combine each user on this list with another user such that no user is assigned to more than one user and no user is assigned to herself.
- The combination has to be random and has to take past combinations into account

*My idea so far:*
- I have this information:

User (A,B,C,D) (the actual number of users ranges between 50 and 400)
Possible combinations: (A-B,A-C,A-D,B-C,B-D,C-D)
Random draw(1): (A-B, C-D)
Random draw(2): (A-D, B-C)
Random draw(3): (A-C, B-D)

- I was able to get all possible combinations using a join of the user table with itself.
- I guess I can take previous draws into account by storing the draws in a separate table and limit the possible combinations to those that are not in this special table.

What I can't do:
- I don't know how to randomly draw from the list of possible combinations such that every user is part of only one combination per draw (e.g. A-B,A-D in the same draw is not allowed)
- I try to use sql or a bit php for this (maybe javascript)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution:

Create a temporary table with a row for each pairing.  Loop over the list of users skipping a random number of empty rows from 1 to the number of empty rows -- insert user.

Easy solution number 2:

Given N users.  Assign each user a unique random number from 1 to N (remove randomly from the set of all numbers from 1 to N).  Pair each user with from 1-N/2 with user from N/2+1 to N.

Comment: I will try to go for number 2: However, as I don't know how to do the random mixing in sql, I might go for Excel and save my outcome in the table of already extablished mixes. Do you have an idea of how to implement a pure sql solution, which does the selecting and the mixing? Thank you

Comment: Why don't you start the solution and see where you get a problem. Then edit your question to include progress and I (or someone else) will help out. I believe SQL does provide a pseudo random number generator to use.  If you are using SQL Server a recursive CTE would probably work best -- but I enjoy them so I might be biased...

Answer (score 0):

The solution is the problem "Bergr (s) table", see Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament.

The latest (best) solution is from Professor Frončeka (Dalibor Froncek, a professor at the University of Minnesota in the US).

For custom solutions, look in the table of solutions n ^ 2.

Comment: Are there any references to this Froncek's solution (I don't see it mentioned in his publications on [his website](http://www.d.umn.edu/~dfroncek/Publications.pdf))...?